# won't show new memes in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I created a meme command, for my discord bot, to show memes from Reddit and post the meme, but the problem is that it will always show old memes and it takes time to post memes in discord, so how to show new ones instead of old ones. I am using python for my bot

code:

````py
@client.command()
async def MEME(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    em = discord.Embed(title = name)

    em.set_image(url = url)

    await ctx.send(embed= em)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://time_filter%20%E2%80%93%20Can%20be%20one%20of:%20all,%20day,%20hour,%20month,%20week,%20year%20(default:%20all).) suggest that `Subreddit.top()` gives you the top all-time posts of a sub, which will most likely be old posts for obvious reasons. You can use the `time_filter` parameter to only get recent posts.

Either get the top posts of *today* using `top(time_filter="day")`, or the top posts of the past *hour* using `top(time_filter="hour")`.

Also, you can get the newest posts using `Subreddit.new()` instead of `top()`, which will always land you new memes (assuming you don't call it twice in a row when no new posts have been made yet).

In case this still isn't what you're looking for, more types of filters (Hot, Rising, ...) can be found on the [API docs for PRAW](http://time_filter%20%E2%80%93%20Can%20be%20one%20of:%20all,%20day,%20hour,%20month,%20week,%20year%20(default:%20all).).